# Data unavailable error message while running script from Runner

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I am trying to run my postman collection with the help of runner option while running the collection I am getting "Data unavailable" Error message and my script stop there itself.

Can anyone please guide me for same.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some more information? What does it say in the console? What is the script?

Comment: @ankit_m I have attached the screenshot please find the same.

Comment: Have chosen the correct environment first? The request is just showing the variables that you entered rather than the actual values.

Comment: @DannyDainton Let me attach new screenshot than the whole picture will be clear.

Comment: Sure, seems a little vague at the moment, the screenshot you posted is after everything has happened and the result of an individual request. You're missing all the set up information.

Comment: @DannyDainton I have uploaded the new image can you please see now?

Comment: I have solved the problem, I missed to add status pass test script under one API call I have made the changes and save it then try to run my collection again and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ongoing issue from postman's end. For workaround you can delete your history and then run your collection.